# The OptaPlanner Benchmarker Report does not display correctly for huge runs

Tags: java, benchmarking, optaplanner

Versions:

- OptaPlanner (all) v8.8.0.Final

I have the Benchmarker running a few huge sets on a remote server and the results do not display correctly.

Expanding the benchmark config, it yields 418 configs, subSingleCount == 10, and I'm using a problem set of size 5.

Each report tries to display results for 418 configs, but the legend of each plot ends up dominating the graph picture.  I would attach a screenshot, but I think that feature is blocked.

I thought maybe the graphs where rendered on the spot, but the graphs are just pictures.

I know that I can regenerate the reports, so are there any power-user/hard-coded settings I can tweak to prevent this/increase the margins/etc.?

I couldn't find anything in the [doc](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.8.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#benchmarker) aside from maybe messing around with the `BenchmarkAggregatorFrame`, but that throws a `NullPointerException` in

`org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.ranking.ScoreSubSingleBenchmarkRankingComparator.compare(ScoreSubSingleBenchmarkRankingComparator.java:28)`

on line 28, so that's a no-go unless I can figure that out.

Complete stack trace as requested is below.  It may be worth mentioning that this does open the application window, too, but it just displays the uncaught exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.ranking.ScoreSubSingleBenchmarkRankingComparator.compare(ScoreSubSingleBenchmarkRankingComparator.java:28)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.ranking.ScoreSubSingleBenchmarkRankingComparator.compare(ScoreSubSingleBenchmarkRankingComparator.java:24)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator2.compare(Collections.java:5231)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1749)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.result.SingleBenchmarkResult.determineRanking(SingleBenchmarkResult.java:403)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.result.SingleBenchmarkResult.determineTotalsAndAveragesAndRanking(SingleBenchmarkResult.java:397)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.result.SingleBenchmarkResult.accumulateResults(SingleBenchmarkResult.java:344)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.result.ProblemBenchmarkResult.accumulateResults(ProblemBenchmarkResult.java:346)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.result.PlannerBenchmarkResult.accumulateResults(PlannerBenchmarkResult.java:331)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.aggregator.swingui.BenchmarkAggregatorFrame.initPlannerBenchmarkResultList(BenchmarkAggregatorFrame.java:262)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.aggregator.swingui.BenchmarkAggregatorFrame.init(BenchmarkAggregatorFrame.java:157)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.aggregator.swingui.BenchmarkAggregatorFrame.createAndDisplay(BenchmarkAggregatorFrame.java:126)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.aggregator.swingui.BenchmarkAggregatorFrame.createAndDisplayFromFreemarkerXmlResource(BenchmarkAggregatorFrame.java:103)
    at com.lmco.victor.main.SatellitePlanningEngineBenchmarkerMain.main(SatellitePlanningEngineBenchmarkerMain.java:52)
```

Comment: Did any benchmarks in the original report, reported as a fail in the report?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet no, no failures as far as I can tell.

Comment: I can provide information on what I see during debug, if helpful.  I know this will be hard to reproduce without the src.

Comment: I presume upgrading to 8.10.0.Final doesn't fix the NPE?
Looking at the code `ScoreDefinition<?> aScoreDefinition = a.getSingleBenchmarkResult().getSolverBenchmarkResult().getScoreDefinition();`, it looks like either the single result or the solver result getter returns null. **I bet this has to do with the fact that `subSingleCount` is in use**, which means it could be a long standing bug (combo aggregator + `subSingleCount`).

Comment: I started a thread here: https://kie.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/232679-optaplanner/topic/subSingleCount.20vs.20aggregator

Comment: I bet the problem lies in `BenchmarkResultIO.readPlannerBenchmarkResultList()`, which returns something (debug it) that has subsingle results that don't have a parent single result.

Comment: Jira: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2521

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet it seems you're right.  I am indeed using subSingleCount (== 10) and each `SubSingleBenchmarkResult` in the list has a null `singleBenchmarkResult`.  

`BenchmarkResultIO::readPlannerBenchmarkResultList` returns a `List<PlannerBenchmarkResult>` each of which has a `List<SingleBenchmarkResult>`, of length one.  That `SingleBenchmarkResult` then has a `List<SubSingleBenchmarkResult>` each of which have `singleBenchmarkResult == null`.  So... yes.

Comment: I wish these comments would allow for slightly more formatting.  Apologies for the wall.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, this is a known issue with large datasets: the graphs become unreadable.

**Workaround**

Run the **Benchmark Aggregator** (no need to rerun the benchmarks) to select a subset of all benchmarks so the graphs become readable.

I see you tried that, and got that NPE. That's weird, can you paste the entire stacktrace? This might be a regression. Normally, if older datasets (run with older optaplanner versions) are in the same directory, and loading them crashes, that doesn't crash the aggregator itself (it just reports those benchmarks as failed to load).

Comment: Sure, one moment.  These were new results, too; each was generated using OptaPlanner v8.8.0 and Benchmarker v8.8.0.

Comment: Updated with stack trace